# Reading input using Assembly (16 bit bootloader)

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader

As a course offered by my uni, I followed a tutorial to write a 16-bit bootloader in Assembly at http://3zanders.co.uk/2017/10/13/writing-a-bootloader/. This part (part 1) is all I'm supposed to have done thus far. It essentially doesn't do anything but print Hello World to the screen.

Now, keeping in mind that this is the only experience I have with writing bootloaders in Assembly (it's the only experience I have, period) - I'm now supposed to expand this into a menu where a user can choose one of three options, and then output a string accordingly, ergo:

```
What is your favourite colour?
Press 1 for red
Press 2 for green
Press 3 for blue

[user input here]

Your favourite colour is [whatever corresponding colour].
```

I've been trying to figure out just where to even start for hours on end now. I have found some examples of a choice menu in Assembly, but the problem is that the code in those examples bares no resemblance whatsoever of what this tutorial here has "taught" me. I feel like I'm being forced to make quite the leap from simply printing Hello World to the screen, to making a menu that prints different output depending on user input.

This is what I currently have:

```
bits 16 ; tell NASM this is 16 bit code
org 0x7c00 ; tell NASM to start outputting stuff at offset 0x7c00
boot:
    mov si,startText ; point si register to startText label memory location
    mov ah,0x0e ; 0x0e means 'Write Character in TTY mode'
.loop:
    lodsb
    cmp al,51
    je blue
    cmp al,50
    je green
    cmp al,49
    je red

    or al,al ; is al == 0 ?
    jz getInput  ; if (al == 0) jump to halt label
    int 0x10 ; runs BIOS interrupt 0x10 - Video Services
    jmp .loop
getInput:
    mov ah,00h
    int 16h
red:
    db "Your favourite colour is red",0
green:
    db "Your favourite colour is green",0
blue:
    db "Your favourite colour is blue",0
halt:
    cli ; clear interrupt flag
    hlt ; halt execution
startText:
    db "",13,10
    db "what is your favourite colour?",13,10
    db "Press one for red",13,10
    db "Press two for green",13,10
    db "Press three for blue",13,10
    db 13,10,0

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0 ; pad remaining 510 bytes with zeroes
dw 0xaa55 ; magic bootloader magic - marks this 512 byte sector bootable!
```

EDIT2:
I've updated the above code once again, attempting to implement what both Sep and John have told me. I realise it isn't how it's supposed to be and certain things that they've told me aren't implemented because I do not yet understand how to.

The problem right now, I think, is that it does not do anything after showing the initial startLabel. Nothing changes if I press any button. If anyone can point me further into the right direction, that'd be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: is it the latest version of your code? could you pleaase update it, i have exactly the same assignment for os, and i still cant manage to do it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You missed one of @SepRoland’s points. Your code in `.loop` loads each individual character, and if it is ***NOT*** `==0` it prints it out and repeats the loop. That means that it is incumbent on you to *provide* the `0` in your data:

```
db "",13,10
```

should be:

```
db 13,10,0
```

(Note that `””` is an empty string - nothing to print - so is unnecessary.)

See the vertical bar (with left tick) on your screen shot? That is actually the computer printing out the opcode for the following `mov` instruction! That garbage output is because your code has stopped printing data, and is now printing the bytes of the actual code. And it will continue to do that until the code happens to have a `0` - which (luckily?) happens to be the very next byte! The above `,0` will prevent all this.

2) OK, so what happens when it does (finally) load a `0`? According to your comments, it will “jump to halt label”. Sure enough, the code then jumps to the `cli` and `hlt` instructions - and the computer halts. It doesn’t get a chance to execute the `mov ah,00h` and `int 16h` that you added below.

You need to move those lines to before the `halt` label - and give them their own label: `getInput` or something. Then change the `jz halt` above to `jz getInput` instead: you want it to get input, not halt!

Then you need to add the code to print out the results. You already know how to print strings: you just need to print out different ones from before - you’ll need new and different labels for these strings. And don’t forget the final `0` each time!

Sep gave you most of what I’ve described; you just haven’t put it all together yet. You need to differentiate in your mind code that the computer will execute versus data that the computer will process. To the PC they’re all just numbers, and it will quite happily execute code and then start to execute data if it runs into it - at least, “happy” until the data makes it do something stupid!

[EDIT]
3) It looks like we need to go back to first principles. Pretend that *you* are the computer, get a piece of paper and a pen, and execute the instructions you've provided. Start at the very top:

- Draw a box, label it `si`, and put `startText` inside it. That's the first `mov`.
- Draw another box, label it `ah`, and put `0x0e` inside it. That's the second `mov`.
- Take mental note of the `.loop` line - you'll need it later.
- The `lodsb` instruction is a little complicated. It uses `si` to look at memory, loads that value into `al` (you'll need a new box), then adds one to `si`. Because `si` holds `startText`, the first byte at `startText` (the `13` - remember, `""` is empty) is loaded into `al`. Put `13` in `al`, and append `+1` inside `si`.

  > Incidentally: take a moment to think about what you've just loaded. It's the first byte of a string of bytes that you want to print out. So pretty soon now you're going to need to call the "print character" routine.
- Now you're comparing `al` with `51` - the ASCII value for `3`, like Sep suggested. (Note that you can actually put `'3'` instead of `51`, to make the code more easy to understand. Note the single (not double) quotes.)

  > Ummm… What's going on here? You loaded a character to print - and now you're checking to see if it's the number 3? Isn't that processing the answer? Before you've asked the computer to even get the answer? Before you've even printed out the string that asks the user to type the answer?

You've added the code that was suggested all right - but completely in the wrong spot. You need to step back and write down what you want the program to do in high-level words before you try to write code that performs those actions.

I suggest you want to do the following:

1. Write out the string asking for which colour the user prefers
2. Get the input from the user
3. If the answer is one of the three expected answers, write out the result.

   Otherwise, write out "Unexpected answer", and go back to step 2.
4. Halt
5. Data to print out

The most important thing is that all this code needs to be together, in the correct order, with no data in the middle. The code not only has to be present, but also in the sequence that you want the computer to execute them.

> What you have is:
>
> 3.If the answer is one of the three expected answers, write out the result.
>
> 1.Write out the string asking for which colour the user prefers
>
> 2.Get the input from the user
>
> 5.Data
>
> 4.Halt
>
> 5.More data

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I've updated my code to what I managed to come up with so far... I think I'm making some (probably very minor) right steps.. but it still doesn't quite doesn't work. I didn't expect it to, as I'm still fairly clueless about this, mind.

Comment: Check my answer for [ EDIT ]

Comment: Thank you. This is all still confusing - the biggest problem is that the tutorial I linked is the ONLY source of information I've had regarding all of this. I know absolutely nothing about it. It is currently 4AM so I'll give it a break. One interesting thing, is that I had to replace the numbers in "Press X for Y-colour" with the words, otherwise the `startText` would mess up. I'm guessing this is because the loop loads that number into `al` at some point, and since I've got that `cmp`, it tries to jump to the corresponding label (which it doesn't do yet, ofc). I'll be back at it tomorrow!

Comment: May I suggest then that after you've had some sleep you re-read everyone's answers? You're missing stuff that has already been explained

Comment: Rest assured, I'm reading everyone's answers very carefully & multiple times over. I'm not missing anything (at least, not in that sense) nor ignoring anything. There are just some things that are not yet clicking because this is completely new to me. Again, I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1):

This will point you in the right direction.

> ```
> hello: 
> db "What is your favourite colour?",13,10
> db "Press 1 for red"13,10
> db "Press 2 for green"13,10
> db "Press 3 for blue"13,10
> db "",13,10
> ```

First correct this message by properly zero-terminating it and not omitting the comma's:

```
hello: 
db "What is your favourite colour?",13,10
db "Press 1 for red",13,10
db "Press 2 for green",13,10
db "Press 3 for blue",13,10
db 13,10,0
```

---

To input you can use BIOS function 00h on the keyboard int 16h:

```
mov ah, 00h
int 16h
```

If the user presses "1", the `AL` register will hold the value 49.
If the user presses "2", the `AL` register will hold the value 50.
If the user presses "3", the `AL` register will hold the value 51.

Now display the common message "Your favourite colour is ". During this action you must guard to not accidentally modify the value in `AL`. Preserve it by using `push ax` ... `pop ax` around this part of your code.

Then test the values you got from reading the keyboard in order to select a pointer (`SI`) to a suitable message. Display that message (just the name of a color). Finally `halt`.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Should I do all this in the `hello:` part of my code? (And yeah, thanks for pointing out the comma errors: I did have them in my actual code, just completely missed them whilst rewriting it on here.